# Invoking the Coffeescript repl

Tags: javascript, python, coffeescript

Is it possible to invoke the Coffeescript repl from a script? It seems to make sense for it to work similar to ipdb in python.

I'm running a coffeescript file from the command line and want to debug my code interactively:

```
> coffee app.coffee
```

Comment: Have you tried [coffee-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee-debug)?

Comment: ultimately that module runs `coffee --nodejs --debug app.coffee`. I did wonder whether the --nodejs arg might be the key but it only partly works. The repl isn't invoked certainly but the debugger statement pauses the browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [thread on the github](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3767) coffee-script issues page pretty much answers my question:

I was close but if you run this command
    `coffee --nodejs --debug app.coffee`

Then just install
`node-inspector` and go to `localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`

Answer (score 0):

It can be used like any other library:

```
(require "coffee-script/repl").start()
```

I don't know how ipdb works, so I can't answer your second part.

Comment: I'm looking to invoke the coffeescript repl from a .coffee file so that I can debug my code interactively. I've had a quick play with your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can debug your compiled javascript with `node debug app.js`. You can set breakpoints with `debugger` in your code

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. You can create source maps that reference your coffeescript source too. It just seems like it must be possible to use the coffeescript repl in a similar manner

Comment: I haven't come upon one yet either. You also can do `coffee --nodejs debug app.coffee` but that also only debugs the javascript.